# In React - useState is not working and not updating the state

Tags: reactjs

Sample snippet added below,

import React, { useState } from 'react';

```
function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({counter:0});
  const add1ToCounter = () => {
    const newCounterValue = state.counter + 1;
    setState({ counter: newCounterValue});
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {state.Counter} times</p>
      <button onClick={add1ToCounter}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer "state.counter" - small letters

```
<p>You clicked {state.counter} times</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little mistakes done by You.
Just replace these below line :
Actully you wrote **"state.Counter"** instead of **"state.counter"**, only capital letter issue.

```
function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({counter:0});
  const add1ToCounter = () => {
    const newCounterValue = state.counter + 1;
    setState({ counter: newCounterValue});
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {state.counter} times</p>
      <button onClick={add1ToCounter}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```